# Conexion php a base de datos SQL Server 2012 desde Linux

Tags: php, linux, pdo, sql-server-2012

Buen día,

Quisiera solicitar su colaboración y conocimientos con un inconveniente que me ha llevado varios días y del cuál no he podido salir, estoy desarrollando una aplicación con php pero necesito conectarme a una base de datos MS SQL SEVER en un servidor externo pero el problema radica en que mi proyecto esta desplegado en un servidor linux (Debian 9) y hasta el momento no he logrado realizar la conexión, ni con la libreria PDO, ni con el driver sqlsrv y mi ultimo intento fue a través de PDO_ODBC pero no he logrado solventar el problema.

Agradezco mucho si alguno de ustedes sabe como puedo conectarme de manera efectiva, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow en español, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A tu pregunta le falta más información, por ejemplo ¿qué mensaje(s) de error específico tienes?, ¿qué cosas ya has intentado y no han funcionado?. Lee el artículo y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar tus probabilidades de obtener buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: Indicanos qué mensaje te da de error, puede que no tengas instalado el driver en el php del servidor, la versión del php debería de ser la 5.4, mira el php info del servidor Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar un sistema de linux a un SQLServer lo puedes hacer usando FreeTDS

```
# apt-get install freetds-dev
```

en tu archivo /etc/freetds/freetds.conf agrega lo siguiente:

```
[servername]
host = your.server.name
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
```

y ahora en tu archivo PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = mssql_connect("servername", "<user>", "<password>");
 mssql_select_db( "Database1", $conn );
 $query_result = mssql_query( "SELECT field1 FROM Table1", $conn );
 echo "The field number one is: ";
 echo mssql_result ($query_result, 0, 0);
 mssql_close($conn); 
 ?>
```